# Linking Programs in different languages to one GUI

Tags: java, python, visual-studio, user-interface

I have a bunch of programs that I have created over the years in different languages and would like to create a GUI where I can link to each program and run it (almost like creating a place to store apps). **I know that I can use Javascript or Visual Studio to create the GUI part, but is it possible to link a python, java, and C program to the same GUI? If so, what is the best program to use in terms of creating a clean looking GUI?**

I found a similar question here: [Merging programs of different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596633/merging-programs-of-different-languages) but I didn't fully understand the answer.

Thanks

Comment: How have you structured your other apps?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "sturctured." As of this moment, I literally have programs that compile and run with things like gcc, netbeans, eclipse, etc. So, maybe the answer is no. Could you explain what you mean by that please?

Comment: It sounds like you want to build a frontend -- a separate program that knows how to launch and/or interact with your other programs.

Comment: @FatalError that is exactly what I want to do, but I wasn't sure if I could do that with different languages